# Bootstrap float-right is not working on a div which I want to align in the right side

Tags: html

I am creating a project where I have to show some data one by one. So I need to put a previous and next button by clicking which user can swich the data.Incase the farst data ,there will be no previous data,so I want to hide the previous button and in case the last data I want to hide the next button. But I want to fix the next button in the right side and previous button in the left. I am trying this code but its not working . I dont no why. Somebody can please help me with this issue? Thanks

```
<div class="row" id="tab-change">
<div class="col-6  d-none" style="" id="prevBtn">
<div class="bg-dark p-10 text-white text-center">
<h5 class="m-b-0 m-t-5"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i> Prev. Chapter</h5>
<small class="font-light" id="prev-chapter">Total Users</small>
</div>           
</div>
<div style="" class="col-6 float-right  d-none"  id="nextBtn">
 <div class="bg-dark p-10 text-white  text-center">
 <h5 class="m-b-0 m-t-5">Next Chapter <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></h5>
 <small class="font-light" id="next-chapter"></small>
 </div>           
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide more of your code so that we can reproduce it locally? Just enough so that we can copy it into our editor and see the issue, consider using: https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/bootstrap

Comment: Remove `.d-none` first so that you can see what you are doing.